# how to set non primary or non unique as foreign key

Tags: sql, database-design

In salary table i cant set WorkExperience,T1,T2 as foreign keys, because those are not primary keys or unique keys of Employee table. what i can do now?

```
create table Employee(
    IdNo int primary key Foreign key References Person (IdNo),
    WorkExperience int,
    PortalNo varchar(3),
    T1 bit NOT NULL,
    T2 bit NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Person FOREIGN KEY (IdNo)
    REFERENCES Person(IdNo)
 );


 create table Salary (
    WorkExperience int,
    T1 bit NOT NULL,
    T2 bit NOT NULL,
    BasicSalary Smallmoney,
    PRIMARY KEY (WorkExperience,T1,T2),
    FOREIGN KEY (WorkExperience,T1,T2) REFERENCES Employee(WorkExperience,T1,T2)
 );
```

Comment: A foreign key can only reference a primary key or unique constraint.

Comment: Perhaps `T1` and `T1` require their won table to be treated as the objects that it sounds like they are. Then that table(s) can act as the foreign key for both your `Employee` table and your `Salary` table?

Comment: the design you're trying to create appears to make no sense. JNevill's suggestion sounds like it might be what you're after, although it's hard to be sure. On what basis are Employee and salary supposed to be linked? What is the logic? Surely the employee's salary is simply a value you enter into a field on their record. Unless it's based on a grading system...in which case just generate a unique SalaryID column in the Salary table as its primary key, and use that in the Employee as a foreign key. The T1, T2 etc fields would then just be attributes of that salary level.Maybe that works better?

Comment: set non primary or non unique as foreign key show that your design in not in Normal Forms.

Answer (score 1):

Treat this as a long formatted comment.

First, Employee.WorkExperience is a bad field because it changes over time.  You would be better off with date fields indicating the original hire data and/or the date he started his current position.

Next, in your salary table, add an autoincrement or uuid field and use that as a primary key.  Create a unique constraint on WorkExperience, T1, and T2.  By the way, give those fields more descriptive names.

Also, in your salary table, do something to account for the fact that widget makers might merit a different salary than ditch diggers.  Even it that's not the case now, it might be later.

Finally, add a not null column to Employee and make it a foreign key to Salary.

Answer (score 1):

This type of salary table is usually configured as a **salary band** or **pay grade**.  Often this might be expressed as a range rather than a specific amount.  Depending on how regimented your pay ranges are, you might need a header and footer, for example "salary band 5" (header) pays $50,000 for 1 year of experience or more (detail), $52,000 for 3 years or more, and $55,000 for 5 years or more (also details).

If the requirement is to be able to work out what an employee is being paid, or what they should be paid, based on a simple set of criteria (length of experience, T1, T2 (whatever they are)) then you should have a pay grade table that has a unique candidate key made up of whatever determinants describe the pay grade level.  This can also have another primary key, like a surrogate key to make foreign keys simpler, but you still need to be able to narrow down to one row in your pay grade table based on business determinants that can be looked up on your employee table.